# Android Arial font - encoding issue

Tags: android, character-encoding, fonts

I am using arial font in my application, which is localised into Polish and German. With both languages I have problem with displaying several letters. I am using UTF-8 coding, but still I am, time by time, seeing rectangles instead of "unknown" letters. Anyone has faced the same problem? Do i need to change XML strings coding?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

In android, you can use any text font to your textview controls, but not in your xml layout files. You should inflate the textview control to TextView instances first. Then load the font from /asset folder and set to those instances as below:

```
 TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.custom); 
  Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/arial.ttf"); 
  tv.setTypeface(face);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am not asking for this simplicity... I have done this, I am facing error, that some character are displayed badly, so I am asking for encoding, I shloud use in my xml string files or any other help concerning not displaying some characters

Comment: @Waypoint: What makes you so sure that this is related to encoding as oppose to something else (for example font fall-back)? I18n defects may have tons of root causes... It's hard to actually tell what have happened from you question.